# Pass directive to input using ion-input wrapper from ionic components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Is there any availability to pass directive to input using a ion-input tag?

What I was trying to do:

```html
<ion-input type="text" name="number" card-number></ion-input>
```

What I want inside ion-input:

```html
<input type="text" name="number" card-number/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in there

> http://edupala.com/ionic-4-custom-directive/

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" [myIonicInput]="yourDerective"></ion-input>
```

.ts

```
  yourDerective: Object = { showUsername: false };
```

Comment: Example  shows the creation of a directive and I already have one from external package working for normal input.